# PHP throwing invalid PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, object, pdo

I'm getting an error which seems to be happening incorrectly.

I've got near enough the same function in a different class and it doesn't seem to happen.
The function I'm using is:

```
public function UserInfo($type, $value) {
    if($type == 'email') {
       $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `accounts` where `provider` = '1' AND `email` = :value AND `type` = 'client' LIMIT 1");
    } else {
       $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `accounts` where `provider` = '2 'AND `prov_id` = :value AND `type` = 'client' LIMIT 1");
    }

    $params = array(":value" => $value,);
    $query->execute($params);
    return $query->FetchObject();
}
```

And I'm trying to get the data via:

`$clients->UserInfo("id", $uid)->email;`

PHP returns the value, so its clear that the object does in fact exist, yet it still throws

`PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/Luke/public_html/manage.php on line 30`

Is there an issue with the syntax I'm using, or is it a PHP bug?

Comment: neither of the two. one of the 2 objects simply doesn't exist

Comment: If PHP tells you something is not an object, then it isn't. Figure out what it is instead and fix the problem.

Comment: do var_dump($clients->UserInfo("id", $uid)) will show if its an object or not

Comment: and, it does return the values its supposed to.

Comment: show us what it returns

Comment: which line is line 30?

Comment: object(stdClass)#7 (5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "12" ["prov_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["type"]=> string(6) "client" ["email"]=> string(20) "test01@thompsonuk.me" ["status"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: Line 30 is the code I pasted, the rest is related to html/css (except including + defining the class)

Comment: Where and how exactly did you take that `var_dump`? Show us a full, complete, self contained example.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.
This won't cause any errors.

```
<?php

class DB {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = PDO(
            'mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8',
            'root', 
            ''
        );
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function UserInfo($type, $value) {
        if ($type == 'email') {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare(
                "SELECT * FROM `accounts` where `provider` = '1' AND `email` = ? AND `type` = 'client' LIMIT 1"
            );
        } else {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare(
                "SELECT * FROM `accounts` where `provider` = '2 'AND `prov_id` = ? AND `type` = 'client' LIMIT 1"
            );
        }
        $stmt->execute(array($value));
        $result = $stmt->fetchObject();
        if ($result === false) {
            throw new Exception('value not found');
        }
        return $result;
    }

}

try {

    $clients = new DB;
    echo $clients->UserInfo("id", $uid)->email;

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think PHP is complaining about this line:

```
$query->execute($params);
```

since the `$query` is not declare outside the if else clause. Another possibility is one query wrong so the `$query` is `False` after `prepare()`: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Could you try:

```
public function UserInfo($type, $value) {
    $sql_query = '';
    if($type == 'email') {
       $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` where `provider` = '1' AND `email` = :value AND `type` = 'client' LIMIT 1";
    } else {
       $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` where `provider` = '2 'AND `prov_id` = :value AND `type` = 'client' LIMIT 1";
    }

    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql_query);
    $params = array(":value" => $value,);

    if ($query === false) return 'False query';

    $query->execute($params);
    return $query->FetchObject();
}
```

Comment: Actually in PHP scoping of `if` is not special, so its not a scope issue. Also, why return a string instead of a boolean?

Comment: If you turn on all errors and notices logging in PHP, it will complain about that if else issue. Returning string is just a demo for @LukeT to have basic idea, he can return whatever he likes.